# Zero-inflated negative binomial model standard error too high?

Tags: r, regression, standard-error, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I've been trying to analyze count data for ant foragers visiting on extrafloral nectaries with R. My data is both overdispersed and zero-inflated, so I used a zero-inflated negative binomial model to analyze the data. I am comparing the foraging frequencies of sick and healthy colonies, so in the model I'm trying to figure out if the treatment (infected, control) significantly affects foraging. I'm using sub-clone colonies, where the original colony is split in to two, so I'm using original colony as a random factor.

I used the glmmTMB-package in R to analyze the data, since it gives me the option of using random factors in zero-inflated models.

```
> da <- read.csv("firstThreeForage.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
> da <- within(da, Treatment <- factor(Treatment))
> da <- within(da, Colony <- factor(Colony))  
> #fitting a poisson model on the data
> fit <- glmmTMB(Foragers~Treatment + (1|Colony), data = da, family = poisson)
> check_zeroinflation(fit)
# Check for zero-inflation

   Observed zeros: 385
  Predicted zeros: 358
            Ratio: 0.93

Model is underfitting zeros (probable zero-inflation).
> check_overdispersion(fit)
# Overdispersion test

       dispersion ratio =   1.162
  Pearson's Chi-Squared = 791.200
                p-value =   0.002

Overdispersion detected.
> #Due to zero-inflation and overdispersion -> ZINB model
> zinb <- glmmTMB(Foragers~Treatment + (1|Colony), ziformula=~Treatment, data = da, family=nbinom1)
> summary(zinb)
 Family: nbinom1  ( log )
Formula:          Foragers ~ Treatment + (1 | Colony)
Zero inflation:            ~Treatment
Data: da

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1520.0   1547.2   -754.0   1508.0      678 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Colony (Intercept) 0.7026   0.8382  
Number of obs: 684, groups:  Colony, 20

Overdispersion parameter for nbinom1 family (): 0.275 

Conditional model:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -0.69941    0.20800  -3.363 0.000772 ***
TreatmentInfected  0.20390    0.09653   2.112 0.034657 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)          -30.07  778986.17       0        1
TreatmentInfected     12.82  778996.00       0        1
```

In the output of the summary, the standard error of the zero-inflation is in the millions and the p-value is 1, which doesn't make any sense whatsoever. I haven't been using zero-inflation models before, and I have no idea why the standard error is so high. I've checked the data and there shouldn't be any issues with it. This is the analysis of the 3 day data, in the 6 day data I have no issues with the zero-inflation model and the output gives me normal figures.

If anyone has any ideas why the output of the ZINB model looks weird or can help me with my code, I would be grateful!